# pspdfkit with arabic text annotation

Tags: angular, pspdfkit

I use web pspdfkit and I use angular 7.

I have problem with arabic text annotation.

the document is saved with arabic text annotation (  the file size in disk is changed )

but the problem when I open the file from disk using acrobat reader the arabic text is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

I work at PSPDFKit. We have responded to your query on support.

I would suggest you to reach our support directly. We offer a blazing fast assistance and the questions are handled directly by the Web team: https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/.

PSPDFKit framework offers an extensive set of API and covers multiple platforms (iOS, macOS, Android, Windows, and Web), they'll surely find a solution that works for you.

Comment: thank you for your response, I already making a request in PSPDFKit support without having a solution for my problem.
I hope to have a solution for my problem